# Compare between 2 variable

Tags: batch-file

```
set "path=\\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\"%COMPUTERNAME%"_"%str2%"_"%PC%".txt"


if %path:!COMPUTERNAME!=%==%path% (
    echo path is same
    pause
    exit
) else (
    echo path is different
    pause
    exit
)
```

it echo "path is same" but it is impossible....i need "path is differnet"
Pleas help. Thx

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Comparing a modification of `%PATH%` against the original `%PATH%` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I dont understand what you tried to do, this line:

```
if %path:!COMPUTERNAME!=%==%path% (
```

... should be written this way:

```
if !path:%COMPUTERNAME%=!==%path% (
```

.. and better this way:

```
if "!path:%COMPUTERNAME%=!" equ "%path%" (
```

Comment: Or even better yet: `if "!path:%COMPUTERNAME%=!" equ "!path!"`. The PATH could contain characters that cause problems with normal expansion.

Comment: @dbenham, and just to make it event better: dont mess with the `path` variable to store filenames.